# How To Re-Render Data On Active Server After Delete - Node/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I have an active server running and I'm trying to perform a `DELETE` request that automatically updates the data. On the front end I have code that captures the active objects information then sends a `DELETE` request `then` a `GET` request for my `JSON` so that it can re-render the data. I'm have trouble figuring out why I have to refresh my webpage to show that the item has been deleted.

```
router.delete('/notes/:id', (req, res) => {
    // Convert the searched id to a number
    const id = Number(req.params.id);
    // See if the id exists in the array
    const deleted = notes.find(notes => notes.id === id);
    // If it does exist
    if(deleted){
        // Filter for all that don't match the id
        const notesArray = notes.filter(notes => notes.id !== id);
        // Rewrite the json file
        fs.writeFileSync(
            path.join(__dirname, '../../db/db.json'),
            JSON.stringify(notesArray, null, 2)
        );
        // Send success
        res.send(200);
    } else {
        res.status(404).send(`Note you're looking for does not exist.`)
    }
})
```

Edit: Adding in front end code to assist

Get Request

```
    router.get('/notes', (req, res) => {
        // When user requests the notes
        // Send the notes in a json format
        res.status(200).json(notes);
    })
```

Front End Code

```
  deleteNote(note.id).then(function() {
    getAndRenderNotes();
    renderActiveNote();
  });

    // Gets notes from the db and renders them to the sidebar
    var getAndRenderNotes = function() {
      return getNotes().then(function(data) {
        renderNoteList(data);
      });
    };

    var getNotes = function() {
      return $.ajax({
        url: "/api/notes",
        method: "GET"
      });
    };

    // Render's the list of note titles
    var renderNoteList = function(notes) {
      $noteList.empty();
    
      var noteListItems = [];
    
      for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
        var note = notes[i];
    
        var $li = $("<li class='list-group-item'>").data(note);
        var $span = $("<span>").text(note.title);
        var $delBtn = $(
          "<i class='fas fa-trash-alt float-right text-danger delete-note'>"
        );
    
        $li.append($span, $delBtn);
        noteListItems.push($li);
      }
    
      $noteList.append(noteListItems);
    };
```

Comment: Ciao, so from the front end you send a DELETE and then you try to GET the data from server again correct?

Comment: Yes. From the front end the request looks like this.
`//delete request
deleteNote(note.id).then(function() {
// get request
    getAndRenderNotes();
//re-render active items
    renderActiveNote();
  });`

Comment: Ok, and the front end waits the server response like `request(DELETE).then(() => request(GET).then(() => { /*here data update*/ }))` ?

Comment: Edited the main post to include that information. There is no second `.then()`

Answer (score 0):

My server returned a `304 - Not Modified` whenever the `GET` request would be completed. Modified the code so that once the `DELETE` request happens then I `find` out if the deleted item exists in my array and if it does then I `redeclare` my `notes` variable as the `filtered` array. From there I rewrite my JSON file using the filtered array.

```
router.delete('/notes/:id', (req, res) => {
    // Convert the searched id to a number
    const id = Number(req.params.id);
    // See if the number exists in the array
    const deleted = notes.find(notes => notes.id === id);
    // If it does exist
    if(deleted){
        // Filter for all that don't match the id
        notes = notes.filter(notes => notes.id !== id);
        // Rewrite the json file
        fs.writeFileSync(
            path.join(__dirname, '../../db/db.json'),
            JSON.stringify(notes, null, 2)
        );
        // Send new notes file
        res.status(200).send('Success');
    } else {
        res.status(404).send(`Note you're looking for does not exist.`)
    }
})
```